# Remove Quotes from String and convert to JSON PHP and Regex

Tags: php, arrays, json, regex

I know there may be some same questions here but I am not able find this solution so i am writing this and needs to know if there is a possiblity for me to remove quotes from string before curly braces and after closing curly braces like this

String before

```
'["{ "zone" : 1, "cat_id" : 1, "subcat" : 1}","{ "zone" 1:, "cat_id" : 1, 
 "subcat" : 2}"]'
```

String after

```
'[{ "zone" :1, "cat_id" : 1, "subcat" : 1},{ "zone" :1, "cat_id" : 1, "subcat" :2}]'
```

Comment: If you need to replace the strings exactly as described in the question, you can use: `str_replace(array('"{', '}"'), array('{', '}'), $str);`. Keep in mind that this is only applicable in the case of similar JSON, such replaces can break the syntax.

Comment: How are you creating the first string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple way

```
$str = '["{ "zone" : 1, "cat_id" : 1, "subcat" : 1}","{ "zone" 1:, "cat_id" : 1,  "subcat" : 2}"]';


$str = str_replace('["{', "[{", $str);
$str = str_replace('}"]', "}]", $str);

$jsonObject = json_decode($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in PHP called `json_encode()` which will correctly encode a JSON String from a PHP data structure like an object or an array.

So first build your data in the data structure you want it in and then run `json_encode()` on it like this

```
$arr = array();

$o = new stdClass();
$o->zone = 1;
$o->cat_id = 1;
$o->subcat = 1;

$arr[] = $o;

$o = new stdClass();
$o->zone = 1;
$o->cat_id = 1;
$o->subcat = 2;

$arr[] = $o;

$json_string = json_encode($arr);

echo $json_string;
```

Result:

```
[{"zone":1,"cat_id":1,"subcat":1},{"zone":1,"cat_id":1,"subcat":2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_replace` to replace the double quotes.

```
$str = '["{ "zone" : 1, "cat_id" : 1, "subcat" : 1}","{ "zone" 1:, "cat_id" : 1, "subcat" : 2}"]';
echo $str;
echo "<br>";
$str = str_replace("}\"]", "}]", str_replace('["{', "[{", $str));
echo $str;
```

Comment: hey it works but when i am using json_decode($str), it is not doing anything, returning null

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one pass using the translation function `strtr`:

```
$str = strtr($str, [ '"{' => '{', '}"' => '}' ]);
```

Obviously this approach will fail if one the value contains `"{` or `}"`.

The best way is to fix the code that produces this wrong JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I have got it done by this method

```
$str = '["{ "zone" : 1, "cat_id" : 1, "subcat" : 1}",
         "{ "zone" 1:, "cat_id" : 1,  "subcat" : 2}"]';

$str = str_replace('["{', "[{", $str);
$str = str_replace('}"]', "}]", $str);
$str = str_replace('}",', "},", $str);
$str = str_replace('"{', "{", $str);
```

This is the way to get the desired result

```
[{"zone":1,"cat_id":1,"subcat":1},{"zone":1,"cat_id":1,"subcat":2}]
```